# How to undo dplyr mutate silently round the division operation

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <-  structure(list(sid = c("MK1", "MK2", "MK3"), nof_reads = c(19786677L, 
29531664L, 1195340L), mapped_reads = c(19785168L, 29529532L, 
1195250L)), .Names = c("sid", "nof_reads", "mapped_reads"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))


dat
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   sid   nof_reads mapped_reads
#>   <chr>     <int>        <int>
#> 1 MK1    19786677     19785168
#> 2 MK2    29531664     29529532
#> 3 MK3     1195340      1195250
```

When I tried the following operation by dividing `mapped_reads` with `nof_reads`, I get this:

```r
> dat %>% mutate(rate = mapped_reads/nof_reads)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  sid   nof_reads mapped_reads  rate
  <chr>     <int>        <int> <dbl>
1 MK1    19786677     19785168 1.000
2 MK2    29531664     29529532 1.000
3 MK3     1195340      1195250 1.000
```

Notice the `rate` column the value is rounded into 1.000. 
Where actually it is this for `MK_1`:

```r
>  19785168/19786677 
[1] 0.9999237
```

How can I resolve the issue, so that it output without rounding.

Comment: works fine on my side

Comment: @Wen Do you mean `dat %>% mutate(rate = mapped_reads/nof_reads)` gives 0.999237 not 1.000 on your side?

Comment: The `rate` column is not actually rounded, it's just that tibbles *display* rounded values. If you look at `dat$rate[1]` you'll see the actual value.

Comment: There was a open github issue somewhere to stop this from happening. Cannot find it at the moment.

Comment: Add `%>% as.data.frame()` at the end of the pipe if you don't like the display format of `tidyverse`.

Comment: So, I believe the answer is you cannot do it in tibble , you need to convert it to data.frame()

Comment: Lots of discussion here: https://github.com/r-lib/pillar/issues/105 and here: https://github.com/r-lib/pillar/issues/40 about this issue. Seems to have been resolved now so that decimals are printed except when they are tiny. Which seems sensible.

Answer (score 0):

```
dat %>% mutate(rate = mapped_reads/nof_reads) %>% as.data.frame()

  sid nof_reads mapped_reads     rate
1 MK1  19786677     19785168 0.999924
2 MK2  29531664     29529532 0.999928
3 MK3   1195340      1195250 0.999925
```